# django 1.7 migrate not updating database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations

I've run `python manage.py makemigrations core` which created the following file in /opt/project/core/migrations

`0001_initial.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Customer',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('company', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('department', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
    ]
```

I then run `python manage.py migrate` and it does nothing.  It's not creating the table in the database.

Running `python manage.py sqlmigrate core` doesn't return a thing.

I'm using postgres as my backend database `db1` and schema is `core`.

Comment: What is the output of the migrate command? Does it say Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
?

Comment: I think I know the problem and I'm troubleshooting it now.  I'm doing multiple databases I believe it's whenever I get the second database in the settings.py

Comment: confirmed this is due to having multiple databases.  Luckly I'm not at the point of adding another one yet so I've removed it for now :)

Comment: Sounds like multiple databases are a mess. Haven't worked with them personally. Glad you resolved your issue.